# Is it possible to make man page from troff format?

Tags: shell, document, manpage, troff

I have a file with troff format and would like to recast to man page

file.txt:

```
.. c:function:: bool is_module_percpu_address (unsigned long addr)

   test whether address is from module static percpu

**Parameters**

``unsigned long addr``
  address to test

**Description**

Test whether **addr** belongs to module static percpu area.

**Return**

``true`` if **addr** is from module static percpu area


.. c:function:: int module_refcount (struct module * mod)

   return the refcount or -1 if unloading

**Parameters**

``struct module * mod``
  the module we're checking

**Return**

     -1 if the module is in the process of unloading
     otherwise the number of references in the kernel to the module
```

I don't really understand the output of groff, when I do `groff file.txt | man -l -`.

As you can see, I have never done man pages, just want to use a troff format and made it a readable man page.

How to do so?

PS: the output comes from perl script `kernel-doc` from source tree provided. I do know whether it is troff format, but the script says so (`Output troff manual page format`)

Comment: read your `man troff` carefully. I'm pretty sure there used to be an `--man` option (or similar). Good luck.

Comment: The output you show is some form of *markdown* format, perhaps reStructuredText. You need to look for further scripts to handle this, perhaps`sphinx`, before you can pass it to groff.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to use troff format and create a readable man page, not necessarily using groff—I'd recommend using pandoc. The below commands result in a much more readable output than using groff.

```
pandoc file.txt -s -t man | man -l -
```

[image]

If your file has any markdown or reStructuredText content as @meuh suggests, that shouldn't be a problem for pandoc.

Answer (score 0):

I hit by chance to a script called `rst2man` written in python which does to converting job. It is not perfect, but better option then `pandoc`. If anyone is trying to for example read kernel documentation. You can do with

```
 kernel-doc path/to/kernel/source.{c,h} | rst2man -q - | man -l -
```

`kernel-doc` is perl script in source tree

`rst2man` is python script

Comment: What makes it better than pandoc, especially if there is markdown or reStructuredText contents?

Comment: I'm still getting familiar with stackexchange; but doesn't your answer to your own question not appropriately address the question?  Is this a situation warranting an edit to the question itself?